# VBA macro to save a powerpoint File with different file Name according to the date

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to save a powerpoint file with different FileName according to the date of next Thursday. That means, if I save the File on 18.10.2016 (which correspend to Tuesday) than the file's name is 20/10/2016 (which correspend to the next thursday).

That's what i wrote but it seems false:

```
Sub SaveAll()
  Dim prs As Presentation
  Dim Todate As Date
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each prs In Presentations
   Todate = DateValue(Now)
    oldWeekDay = Weekday(Todate)
    Select Case oldWeekDay

    Case 1
    prs.saveAs "C:\Users\Moez\Desktop\Macro_Project\Todate + 4.pptm"
    Case 2
    prs.saveAs "C:\Users\Moez\Desktop\Macro_Project\Todate + 3.pptm"
    Case 3
    prs.saveAs "C:\Users\Moez\Desktop\Macro_Project\Todate + 2.pptm"
    Case 4
    prs.saveAs "C:\Users\Moez\Desktop\Macro_Project\Todate + 1.pptm"
    Case 5
    prs.saveAs "C:\Users\Moez\Desktop\Macro_Project\Todate.pptm"
    Case 6
    prs.saveAs "C:\Users\Moez\Desktop\Macro_Project\Todate + 6.pptm"
    Case 7
    prs.saveAs "C:\Users\Moez\Desktop\Macro_Project\Todate + 5.pptm"

    End Select

  Next prs

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: "it seems false" what seems false?

Comment: First, "20/10/2016" is not a valid file name (at least on windows). You can't use / in filenames. Second, you are using static strings for names, while you should "build" the filename using concatenation (with `&`) and Date to String conversion (which is usually done with `Format` function).

Comment: And last, you are saving all `prs` in `Presentations` under the same name, they will overwrite each other.

Answer (score 1):

To add days to a date use `DateAdd`. You can calculate the number of days to add unsing `(7 + numberOfDayYouWant - numberOfDayYouHave) Mod 7`

```
Dim nextThursday As Date
Dim strDate As String
Dim Todate As Date
Todate = Date 'the "Date" function returns the date portion of "Now"

'find the next thursday
 nextThursday = DateAdd("d", (12 - Weekday(Todate)) Mod 7, Todate)

'make a string
strDate = Format(nextThursday, "yyyy-mm-dd") 'edit format as you wish

'now save the presentation, e.g.
'Set prs = someting
prs.SaveAs "C:\Users\Moez\Desktop\Macro_Project\" & strDate & ".pptm"
```

It's up to you to make sure you don't save your presentations under the same name

Comment: `Todate = DateValue(Now)` could be replaced by `Todate = Date()`

Comment: True, I left it in because it was OP's and I didn't want to cause confusion between the function and the type